# entry widget validation with tkinter for both integers and floating point values

Tags: validation, tkinter, floating-point, integer, widget

So i have some code which can be used to validate an entry widget so that only integer values can be inputted. I would like to achieve the same effect but instead of only integer values both integer values AND floating point value are excepted.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def testVal(inp,acttyp):
    if acttyp == '1': #insert
        if not inp.isdigit():
            return False
    return True
entry = Entry(root, validate="key")
entry['validatecommand'] = (entry.register(testVal),'%P','%d')
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? What part of the problem don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `float()` on the input text to determine whether it is integer or float:

```
from tkinter import *

def validate_entry(inp):
    try:
        float(inp)
    except:
        return False
    return True

root = Tk()
Entry(root, validate='key', vcmd=(root.register(validate_entry), '%P')).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. However, one problem that i have encountered when using this was that when deleting values from the entry widget, the first value seems to not get deleted. I have tried clearing the entry with Entry.delete(0, END) however it doesnt work when this validation is applied to the entry widget.

Comment: It is because empty string cannot be converted to float.  If you want it, just return True if the input is empty.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x. Input restricted to decimal and scientific notation with 2-digit exponent.
Not allowing to exit the text box if the number is invalid.
Not allowed "+" sign

```py
    #Input restricted to decimal and scientific notation with 2-digit exponent
    #Not allowing to exit the text box if the number is invalid
    #Not allowed "+" sign
    #=========================================================================
    import tkinter as tk
    import re
    
    def validation(text,action,W):
        if action == "focusout":
            #not allowing to exit the text box if the number is invalid
            widget = root.nametowidget(W)
            try:
                num = float(widget.get())
                return True
            except:
                widget.focus_set()
                return True           
            return True
        if action == "key":
            #does not allow beginning with "e"
            if text != "":
                if text[0] in ["e","E"]:
                    return False
            #does not allow beginning with ".e" o ".E"
            if len(text) == 2:
                if ".e" in text or ".E" in text:
                    return False 
            #does not allow the combinations indicated
            if bool([i for i in ["-e","-E","-.e","-.E"] if (i in text)]):
                return False
            #does not allow "-" after digit and before "e" or "E"
            if "e" not in text and "E" not in text:
                if "-" in text[1:]:
                    return False
            result = re.match(r"(\-)?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*(e|E)?\-?[0-9]{0,2}$", text)
            return result is not None
        return True
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    entry1 = tk.Entry(root, validate="all", validatecommand=(root.register(validation), "%P","%V","%W") )
    entry1.grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    label = tk.Label(root, text="(<-input number")
    label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    entry2 = tk.Entry(root)
    entry2.grid(row=1, column=0)
    
    root.mainloop()
```

You can see mores cases  [here](http://www.xente.mundo-r.com/explora/Python/Python-restringir%20entrada%20de%20datos%20en%20Entry%20de%20Tkinter.html) .

Answer (score 0):

So, if You want Your code to validate only integer and floats, You can try this way:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def testVal(inp,acttyp,val):
    if acttyp == '1': #insert
        if inp.startswith('.'): # May be unexpected behavior if leave True
            return False
        elif val.count('.') > 1:
            return False 
        elif inp.isdigit():
            return True
        elif inp.icontain('.'):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True
entry = Entry(root, validate="key")
entry['validatecommand'] = (entry.register(testVal),'%S','%d','%P')
entry.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

My Basic Function **isfloat()** for the Tkinter Entry Widget Float Validation with Limits (-90.00 to 90.00)

```
from tkinter import *

def isfloat(P):
    if (P == "" or P == "-"):
        return True
    else:
        c=0
        i,j,k,l=1,1,1,1
        for x in P:
            if(i==2):
                if(j==2):
                    if(k==1):
                        if(x=='1' or x=='2' or x=='3' or x=='4' or x=='5' or x=='6' or x=='7' or
                           x=='8' or x=='9' or x=='0' or x=='.'):
                            c+=1
                            if(x=='.'):k=2
                    elif(k==2):
                        if(x=='1' or x=='2' or x=='3' or x=='4' or x=='5' or x=='6' or x=='7' or
                           x=='8' or x=='9' or x=='0'):
                            c+=1
                elif(j==1):
                    if(l==1):
                        if(x=='1' or x=='2' or x=='3' or x=='4' or x=='5' or x=='6' or x=='7' or
                           x=='8' or x=='9' or x=='0' or x=='.'):
                            c+=1
                            j=2
                            if(x=='.'):k=2
                    elif(l==2):
                        if(x=='1' or x=='2' or x=='3' or x=='4' or x=='5' or x=='6' or x=='7' or
                           x=='8' or x=='9' or x=='0'):
                            c+=1
                            j=2                        

            elif(i==1):
                if(x=='1' or x=='2' or x=='3' or x=='4' or x=='5' or x=='6' or x=='7' or
                   x=='8' or x=='9' or x=='0' or x=='-'):
                    c+=1
                    i=2
                    if(x=='-'):l=2
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False
        #For latitude calculation, 'P' is the number, '-90.0' is the from, '-90.0' is the to
        if(c==len(P) and float(P)<=90.0 and float(P)>=-90.0):
            return True
        else:
            return False

def prt():
    if(col[0].get()!=""):print(float(col[0].get()), "\t", type(float(col[0].get())))
    else:False

setup=Tk()
setup.geometry("200x200")           
col,d=[],[]         
col.append(StringVar())
d.append(Entry(setup, textvariable=col[0], width=15, validate='all', validatecommand=((setup.register(isfloat)), '%P')))
d[0].grid(row=0,column=0)
Button(setup,text="Print",command=prt).grid(row=1,column=0)
setup.mainloop()
```